# Setting up CMUSphinx/PocketSphinx on Windows 7

Tags: python, linux, automation, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I have been trying this for hours now, but cannot seem to get this right. I am trying to download Pocketsphinx for use of command recognition in Python.

So first thing I did was attempt to install SphinxBase, which is required for Pocketsphinx to work. So here we go. I downloaded the files, the tar.gz zip. I followed the instructions in the README document in order to install on windows.

```
To compile sphinxbase in Visual Studio 2010 Express (or newer):
1, unzip the file.
2, rename the directory to sphinxbase
3, go into the sphinxbase folder and click sphinxbase.sln
4, in the menu, choose Build -> Rebuild All -> Batch Build -> Build
```

I have never used visual before, but it seemed pretty self explanatory. First thing I did was unzip and rename. Next up I opened the SLN project in visual, selected all 6 projects, the Files>Build Selection. It build with all 6 projects succeeding. Great, that's done. Now was that really all? I had to do?

Next up was PocketSphinx. I downloaded the tar.gz again, and basically did the same process.

```
 * load pocketsphinx.sln in pocketsphinx directory
 * compile all the projects in PocketSphinx
```

All builds succeeded in being built. So... done, right? After this, I am lost. Most tutorials stop here and do not actually go into using Pocketsphinx in other languages. I need to be able to use it in Python.

So I did some digging around and found a setup_win32.py file under pocketsphinx/python. I tried to run this in the command prompt but go multiple errors. Now I am running windows 64 bit, but could this cause this issue?
http://hastebin.com/japobecusi.tex

So all in all, I just need help getting this to work with Python. I am very inexperienced in these things currently. Thanks

One more thing, I am considering switching to my Ubuntu Linux partition in order to almost make it easier on myself. Most programs, including this one, seem to only use windows 32, like 64 is unacceptable apparently. So would it benefit me to move over to a Linux platform to work in Python? Would it be easier?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: i can't found any .sln file when i downloaded pocketsphinx .

Answer (score 1):

It is not that trivial to build python with swig on windows. You can just pick latest prebuilt binaries here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPocketSphinx/12608

At the corresponding repository https://github.com/bambocher/PyPocketSphinx you can find more detailed manual on how to build it.

Please note that for latest features you need a latest pocketsphinx version from github/subversion repository, a packaged 0.8 is not going to work.

Switch to Linux is also a good idea.

Comment: Wow that was simple. Okay now I am using a code you told someone to do. http://hastebin.com/yegulacako.vhdl
I am getting saying "p" is not defined. I would try to fix it myself, but I do not know what "p" is supposed to be. Thanks @Nikolay Shmyrev

Comment: p = paudio.PyAudio(). You can also use paudio.PyAudio.open.